# Animating/Referencing dynamic elements with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I have a number of dynamically created elements that I want to later animate.  I know that dynamic elements can by referenced using:

```
$(document).on(event, selector, cb)
```

but I am not sure how to implement this with animate.  Here is my code if it helps.  "state.headings" and "state.text" reference the dynamic elements

```
var state = {
  sm: () => {return $(window).width() < "576"},
  blocks: [
    $("#first-block"),
    $("#second-block")
  ],
  pairs: [
    $("#first-pair"),
  ],
  headings: [
    $("#first-heading"),
    $("#second-heading"),
  ],
  text: [
    $("#first-text"),
    $("#second-text"),
  ],
  watching: 0,
}

$(window).on("scroll", () => {
  if (state.sm()) {
    if (isInViewport(state.blocks[state.watching])) {
      if (state.headings[state.watching].css("right") !== "0px") {
        state.headings[state.watching].animate({
          right: "0px"
        })
        state.text[state.watching].animate({
          left: "0px"
        }, () => {
          if (state.watching < state.blocks.length -1){
            state.watching++ 
          }
        })
      }
    }
  } else {
    //handle animations for larger devices
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around it by setting my selectors to regular strings and using

```
$(document.getElementById(selector)).animate()
```

but I am still interested to know if jQuery provides its own solution.